# Jquery delay disabled

Tags: jquery, html

Why the following code doesn't work? I want that input would be disabled for a one second and then it would go normal again.

```
$('#chat_bg').attr('disabled', true).delay(1).$('#chat_bg').attr('disabled', false);
```

Comment: Because `delay(1).$('#chat_bg')` is not valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aside from the syntactically invalid JavaScript, and the fact that [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) interprets the argument as milliseconds, not seconds:

`.delay()` only affect the `events` queue by default, which `.attr()` does not interact with.

Keep it simple, and just use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout).

```
var $elt = $('#chat_bg').attr('disabled', true);
setTimeout(function ()
{
    $elt.attr('disabled', false);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`queue` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue2) to add a function to (in this case) the `fx` queue:

```
$('#chat_bg').prop('disabled', true).delay(1000).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', false);
    next();
});
```

[`delay` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/delay) takes the time in milliseconds and only effects functions that are work on the `fx` queue. Most functions are not added to any queue at all, like `attr`. In this case you have to explicitly put a function in the queue (as shown above).

Also, as you set boolean values, you should use [`prop` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/prop) instead.

---

Or simply use `setTimeout`, as [@Matt describes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554296/jquery-delay-disabled/6554312#6554312).